# The relation between Wolf's and Teichmüller's parametrization of the Teichmüller space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, teichmuller-theory, fuchsian-groups

Let $\mathcal{T}_g$ be the Teichmüller space of Riemannian surface structures on an oriented 2-dimensional manifold of genus $g$. Fix a point $S \in \mathcal{T}_g$. There are two different ways to parametrize $\mathcal{T}_g$ by quadratic differentials on $S$:

1. The first one goes back to Teichmüller and is based on the theory of quasi-conformal maps. For a Riemannian surface $S' \in \mathcal{T}_g$ and a diffeomeorphism $f_0 \colon S \to S'$ there exists a unique quasi-conformal map $f \colon S \to S'$ which is homotopic to $f_0$ and minimizes the dilatation coefficient. This map is defined by its Beltrami differential $\mu_f$. Beltrami differential is a $(-1,1)$-form and using the metric one can produce from it a quadratic differential $q_f \in Q(S):= H^0(S, K^2_S)$. Since $f$ is quasi-conformal, $||q_f||_1 \le 1$. The Teichmüller theorem says that this establishes a diffeomorphism $\beta \colon \mathcal{T}_g \to Q_1(S)$, where $Q_1(S) \subset Q(S)$ is the unit ball (in $L^1$-metric).
2. The second one was proposed by Wolf and is based on the theory of harmonic maps. Again, fix a Riemannian surface $S'$ and a diffeomorphism $f_0 \colon S \to S'$. Let $u_{S'} \colon \pi_1(S') \to \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the uniformization representation. Put $\rho:= u_{S'} \circ \pi_1(f)$. This is a discrete irreducible $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$-representation of $\pi_1(S)$ and by Corlette-Eels-Sampson theory there exists a unique $\rho$-equivariant harmonic map $\phi \colon \widetilde{S} \to \mathbb{H}$ (where $\widetilde{S}$ is a universal covering of $S$ and $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper-half plane with the Poincarè-Lobachevsky metric $d_H$). The Hopf differential $q_{\phi}:= (\phi^*d_H)^{2,0}$ turns out to be a holomorphic quadratic differential on $S$, and this defines a diffeomorphism $\eta \colon \mathcal{T}_g \to Q(S)$.

My question is this: what is known about the relation between these two approaches? For instance, is there a chance to describe the map $\beta \circ \eta^{-1} \colon Q(s) \to Q(S)$?

Comment: I am quite sure that there is no reasonable description of the composition (besides just the definition).